# SQL Server: JOIN on the result given by MAX statement within SELECT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

My goal is to do a `JOIN` on the result of the `MAX` statement that resides within the overarching `SELECT` to show a different field to which the result of the `MAX` statement is related from a different table.

Below the current query I wrote so far:

```
SELECT 
        'Status' = 
            MAX(
                CASE PMCCONTRACTSTATUSLOG.STATUS 
                    WHEN '3' THEN PMCCONTRACT.RENTALOBJECTID
                    ELSE ''
                END)
        ,PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTID
        ,PMCCONTRACTSTATUSLOG.STATUS
        ,PMCCONTRACT.RENTALOBJECTID
FROM PMCCONTRACT
LEFT JOIN PMCCONTRACTSTATUSLOG
    ON PMCCONTRACTSTATUSLOG.CONTRACTID = PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTID
GROUP BY 
    PMCCONTRACT.CONTRACTID
    ,PMCCONTRACT.RENTALOBJECTID
    ,PMCCONTRACTSTATUSLOG.STATUS
```

Result of this current query:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (     
TEST            NVARCHAR(255)   ,
CONTRACTID      NVARCHAR(255)   ,
STATUS          NVARCHAR(255)   ,
RENTALOBJECTID  NVARCHAR(255)   
);
INSERT INTO Test (TEST, CONTRACTID, STATUS, RENTALOBJECTID)
VALUES
('VGO0000001','HC000001','3','VGO0000001'),
('VGO0000002','HC000002','3','VGO0000002'),
('','HC000003','2','VGO0000004'),
('','HC000004','2','VGO0000005'),
('VGO0000006','HC000005','3','VGO0000006'),
('VGO0000008','HC000006','3','VGO0000008'),
('','HC000007','2','VGO0000011'),
('','HC000008','2','VGO0000013'),
('','HC000009','2','VGO0000014'),
('','HC000010','2','VGO0000015')
SELECT * FROM Test
```

And within my first query I want to join field `Test2.TEST` from the table below to field `Test.TEST` from the table above, and show `Test2.NAME`. Below the second table `Test2`:

```
CREATE TABLE Test2 (        
TEST    NVARCHAR(255)   ,
NAME    NVARCHAR(255)   
);
INSERT INTO Test2 (TEST, NAME)
VALUES
('VGO0000014','100'),
('VGO0000015','101'),
('VGO0000001','87'),
('VGO0000002','88'),
('VGO0000004','90'),
('VGO0000005','91'),
('VGO0000006','92'),
('VGO0000008','94'),
('VGO0000011','97'),
('VGO0000013','99')
SELECT * FROM Test2
```

Comment: Use a CTE or subquery in the `FROM`.

Comment: Of course! Thanks.